# I need the ellipse to remain centered and move back and forth along the length of the line

Tags: javascript, animation, processing, processing.js

The code is a snippet from the program that I am writing for a project, using the processing.js library.  I need the ellipse to travel along the entire length of the diagonal line while remaining centered on the line.  When complete, there will be a total of eight lines with the ellipse sliding back and forth.  This is the fifth line.  You will notice that I had to create a special speed variable in order to get the sphere to move down the diagonal (two other diagonal lines in the code work without this).

It works on all other lines in the graphic.  This one travels down perfectly,  then goes "off-track" on the way up; when it reaches the top, it just bounces in an odd (random-looking) way.  Can I fix it without changing the basic format?  Thank you!

```
var x5 = 113;
var y5 = 27;
var speed5 = 1;
var speed5y = speed5 * 2;

draw = function() {
   //lineBallFive
     line(100, 1, 300, 400); 
       fill(0, 225, 255);
       ellipse(x5, y5, ballSize, ballSize);
         if (x5 > 300)  {
             speed5 = -3;   
         }
         if (x5 < 100)  {
             speed5 = 3;   
         }
         if (y5 > 400)  {
             speed5y = 2 * -3;   
         }
         if (y5 < 1)  {
             speed5y = 3;   
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the ellipse relative to itself, you can use the [`lerp()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/lerp_/) function to move the ellipse using linear interpolation. This will make it much easier to sync up your lines.

Here's a little example:

```
var amount = 0;
var speed = .001;

function setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {

  var startX = 0;
  var startY = 0;
  var endX = width;
  var endY = height;
  var currentX = lerp(startX, endX, amount);
  var currentY = lerp(startY, endY, amount);

  background(0);
  ellipse(currentX, currentY, 20, 20);

  amount += speed;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.  I am working on a solution to my problem using your code.  I will let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: @javaDrinker Did you ever get this sorted out?